how to extract and modify an XFS file
I'm currently trying to modify a firmware of an electric car from china. I have the firmware unpacked and it contains images (I suppose?) of it's partitions. All of them are *.XFS I need to extract one of them (system.xfs) to modify it and then pack it again and flash to my emmc. Any clues on how to modify XFS files?
tried to mount it on widows and linux, but couldn't do that.
